# probability and combinations with the word examination

Tags: probability

how the word >examination< can be written different types. Is the solution is 11!/2! X 2! X 2! = 11!/8. Please help to get the value

Regards,

me

Comment: It is very unclear what you're asking. Could you try to rephrase the question with different words (and more of them), please?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have seen the exact problem before. I think he is asking how many words can be written using exactly those letters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find this in Combinatorial Problems and Exercises by Laszlo Lovasz?

$examination=e*x*a^2*m*i^2*n^2*t*o$

If all of the letters where different there would be $11!$ ways to permute it. However there are $2*2*2=8$ permutations that look exactly the same, (since the letters a,i and n can be arranged in two ways each, without any noticeable difference). therefore each permutation belongs to a class of 8 permuations which all look the same. Therefore there are $\frac{11!}{8}$ classes and thus $\frac{11!}{8}$ words, you are correct.